# How do I store shell command results in a variable in sql?

Tags: shell, mariadb

My system is Ubuntu 16.04 and MariaDB version is 10.2.38.

I want to get Ubuntu version from shell and save the result in sql variable.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> \! lsb_release -r;
Release:        16.04
```

I executed the sentence below.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> set @ver = '\! lsb_release -r';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But the value stored in the @ver variable disappointed me.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select @ver;
+------------------+
| @ver             |
+------------------+
| ! lsb_release -r |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I wonder how I can save the value 16.04 in a variable. Thank you.

Comment: Generally is safer if the SQL server cannot just execute commands on the OS which is why it isn't implemented. But seriously, why is exposing this important? Welcome to SO.

Comment: `\!` commands are executed by the client with no server involvement. They can't be combined.

Comment: I edited to make it more clear that you're using MariaDB, not MySQL. MariaDB started in 2010 as a fork of MySQL, but both products have changed independently since then, and they are no longer compatible. You should not think of MariaDB as "a type of MySQL." They are different products now.

Answer (score 2):

`\!` is a mariadb (and mysql) command line extension to execute shell commands for maintenance. It will be executed on the client, not on the server and cannot be mixed with SQL commands.

SQL doesn't support execution of other programs - this feature would be a huge security risk.

To store output from a shell command in a SQL variable you can use the --init_command option when starting the command line client:

```
$ mariadb --init-command="set @a:=right(\"`lsb_release -r`\",5)"
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 3938
Server version: 10.10.3-MariaDB-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> select @a;
+-------+
| @a    |
+-------+
| 20.04 |
+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered on the POSIX shell level: Since `lsb_release -r` prints *Release:        16.04* on standard output, the command

```
lsb_release -r | cut -d " " -f 2
```

should print just *16.04*.

Answer (score 0):

If you where using a not [end-of-maintaince version](https://mariadb.org/about/#maintenance-policy) where MariaDB was packaged by upstream, then in the last 1-2 releases it was stored in `@@version` at the end:

```
select RIGHT(@@version,4)

RIGHT(@@version,4)
2204
```

Comment: Sorry, but the point of my question is that the value stored in the variable is not the result of the shell command, but the string is stored.